# Copy files older than 2 days only in from Azure Blob CentOS & Windows

Tags: centos, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to setup a crontab to download files from blob into my local folder in CentOS using AZCopy10. Currently I was able to hardcode the date & extract the files modified post the date. Below is how I do it.

azcopy copy 'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/blobxxx?SASKEY' '/azblob' --include-after '2021-01-27T14:00:00Z' --recursive

I am looking for some help to pass the date as a variable where it looks for files not older than 2 days. I have tried passing date as **date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M'** but can't seem to get it to work.

Has anyone worked on the same. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it. Or please tell me what's else you need.

Comment: Hi Charles, Thank You for you help. This works within the OS perfectly. I am trying to make changes to my script & hopefully should work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to get the time two days before today and set it as a variable both in Linux and Windows like the format `2021-01-27T14:00:00Z`. Here is an example.

Linux:

```
two_days_ago=$(date -d "-2 days" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)
```

It shows like this:

[image]

Windows:

```
$two_days_ago=(Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

It shows like this:

[image]